Pandoc to LaTeX Conversion Problem
I tried to convert an article from Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy that contains symbolic logic notations from ".html" to ".tex". I used Pandoc like this:
pandoc -o article.html -s article.tex

The problem is that when I got the .tex file, I find that those mathematical/logical notations have been converted in a strange syntax!!
we interpret predication

{}\phantomsection\label{MathJax-Element-107-Frame}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-939}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-940}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-941}{{X}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-942}{{(}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-943}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-944}{{t}}}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-945}{{1}}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-946}{{,}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-947}{{\ldots{}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-948}{{,}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-949}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-950}{{t}}}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-951}{{n}}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-952}{{)}}}}{(X(t_{1},\ldots,t_{n}))}}
as membership
{}\phantomsection\label{MathJax-Element-108-Frame}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-953}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-954}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-955}{{(}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-956}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-957}{{t}}}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-959}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-960}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-961}{{M}}}}}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-958}{{1}}}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-962}{{⟨}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-963}{{s}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-964}{{⟩}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-965}{{,}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-966}{{\ldots{}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-967}{{,}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-968}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-969}{{t}}}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-971}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-972}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-973}{{M}}}}}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-970}{{n}}}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-974}{{⟨}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-975}{{s}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-976}{{⟩}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-977}{{)}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-978}{{∈}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-979}{{s}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-980}{{(}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-981}{{X}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-982}{{)}}}}{((t_{1}^{\mathfrak{M}}\langle s\rangle,\ldots,t_{n}^{\mathfrak{M}}\langle s\rangle) \in s(X))}}.
Any idea how I can convert those notations in a normal syntax?

I can only see standard hyperref commands there, does it work without error in a tex document if you have just that in a math mode in a document just using hyperref amsymb amsfonts

you gave the link elsewhere to https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/  pandoc is converting the mathjax generated html to tex which you do not need to do as the source is tex already. Just take the linked file in an editor and make some simple replaces <p> to blank line <h2> to \section and you will have latex

The SEP contains inline math enclosed in \( and \):
<p>
In clause 1 of the above definition we follow the common practice of
giving a set-theoretical interpretation to the predication
\(X(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\). Having interpreted <i>X</i> as a subset of
\(M^n\), we interpret predication \(X(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\) as membership
\((t^\mm_1 \langle s\rangle,\ldots,t^\mm_n \langle s\rangle) \in
s(X)\). In clause 2 we interpret quantification over properties and
relations as quantification over subsets of the cartesian product
\(M^n\). Respectively, in clause 3 we interpret quantification over
functions as quantification over sets that are functions \(M^n\to M\)
in the set-theoretical sense.</p>


You can tell pandoc to parse math like this by adding the extension tex_math_single_backslash:
pandoc logic-higher-order.html --from=html+tex_math_single_backslash -o logic-higher-order.tex, resulting in the following latex code:
In clause 1 of the above definition we follow the common practice of
giving a set-theoretical interpretation to the predication
\(X(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\). Having interpreted \emph{X} as a subset of
\(M^n\), we interpret predication \(X(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\) as membership
\((t^\mm_1 \langle s\rangle,\ldots,t^\mm_n \langle s\rangle) \in
s(X)\). In clause 2 we interpret quantification over properties and
relations as quantification over subsets of the cartesian product
\(M^n\). Respectively, in clause 3 we interpret quantification over
functions as quantification over sets that are functions \(M^n\to M\) in
the set-theoretical sense.


the code only uses standard amsmath and hyperref commands. It produces lots of errors about multiple labels, and one for an undeclared Unicode character  but typesets as


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\[
  {}\phantomsection\label{MathJax-Element-107-Frame}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-939}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-940}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-941}{{X}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-942}{{(}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-943}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-944}{{t}}}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-945}{{1}}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-946}{{,}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-947}{{\ldots{}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-948}{{,}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-949}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-950}{{t}}}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-951}{{n}}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-952}{{)}}}}{(X(t_{1},\ldots,t_{n}))}}
\]
as membership
\[
 {}\phantomsection\label{MathJax-Element-108-Frame}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-953}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-954}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-955}{{(}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-956}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-957}{{t}}}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-959}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-960}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-961}{{M}}}}}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-958}{{1}}}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-962}{{⟨}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-963}{{s}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-964}{{⟩}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-965}{{,}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-966}{{\ldots{}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-967}{{,}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-968}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-969}{{t}}}{{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-971}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-972}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-973}{{M}}}}}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-970}{{n}}}}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-974}{{⟨}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-975}{{s}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-976}{{⟩}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-977}{{)}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-978}{{∈}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-979}{{s}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-980}{{(}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-981}{{X}}\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-982}{{)}}}}{((t_{1}^{\mathfrak{M}}\langle s\rangle,\ldots,t_{n}^{\mathfrak{M}}\langle s\rangle) \in s(X))}}
  \]
\end{document}

removing \phantomsection and \label  and adding a definition for \in it produces

without error
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,hyperref}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2208}{\in}
\begin{document}

\[
  {}{{{{{X}}{{(}}{{{{t}}}{{{1}}}}{{,}}{{\ldots{}}}{{,}}{{{{t}}}{{{n}}}}{{)}}}}{(X(t_{1},\ldots,t_{n}))}}
\]
as membership
\[
 {}{{{{{(}}{{{{t}}}{{{{{{M}}}}}{{{1}}}}}{{⟨}}{{s}}{{⟩}}{{,}}{{\ldots{}}}{{,}}{{{{t}}}{{{{{{M}}}}}{{{n}}}}}{{⟨}}{{s}}{{⟩}}{{)}}{{∈}}{{s}}{{(}}{{X}}{{)}}}}{((t_{1}^{\mathfrak{M}}\langle s\rangle,\ldots,t_{n}^{\mathfrak{M}}\langle s\rangle) \in s(X))}}
  \]
\end{document}


Isn't there any better way to convert .html files containing mathematical notation to .tex without pandoc?

@TeXman you gave no clue of the source but I would guess from the labels thet the html source was not really html but a tex expression converted to html on the fly by mathjax javacript, so if converting to tex you would be better not to convert those fragments at all but simply re-use them from the original file.

I took the source code of the Stanford Encyclopaedia page and save it as an .html file. Then I used pandoc to convert it to .tex. The notations should be written like this in the converted file:
\[\tag{3}\label{XY} \forall x_1\ldots \forall x_n(X(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\leftrightarrow Y(x_1,\ldots,x_n)) \] 
but instead, I keep getting those "phantomsection\label {MathJax-Element-107-Frame}{\phantomsection\label{MJXc-Node-939}" weird lines!

@TeXman link to the page? but anyway the tex you show in the question is almost certainly a closer literal translation of the mathjax generated html than the tex you suggest, (for example it lets me guess the html page was using mathjax) but as I say I suspect the original tex is in the page and you could just use that. They are not "weird lines" they are the natural translation of the html markup in the page you are translating
